# Firebase ordered automatically without priority?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I'm trying to order data with priority key. I put the priority only "list" as showing below.

Here is example similar to my code

```
[listRef observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded andPreviousSiblingNameWithBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot, NSString *prevName) {

    //get listID
    NSString* listID = snapshot.name;

    //get detail for list
    [[detailRef childByAppendingPath:listID] observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        NSString* text = snapshot.value[@"listtext"];
        ・
        ・
      }];
}];
```

It's working properly.Ordered list is shown.

However I have problem when referring user data like below.

```
[listRef observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded andPreviousSiblingNameWithBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot, NSString *prevName) {

    //get listID
    NSString* listID = snapshot.name;

    //get detail for list
    [[detailRef childByAppendingPath:listID] observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        NSString* text = snapshot.value[@"listtext"];
        NSString* userID = snapshot.value[@"user"];
        ・
        ・
       //added code
        Firebase* userRef = [[self.firebase childByAppendingPath:@"person"] childByAppendingPath:userID];
        [userRef observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
                avatarImageURL = snapshot.value[@"image"];
                username = snapshot.value[@"name"];
                ・

            }];

      }];
}];
```

This code doesn't return ordered data by listRef priority. It seems like order by userRef but it don't have priority.

Here is json data.

```
"person" : {
 "1321312" : {
  "uid" : "1321312",
  "name" : "testuser",
  "image" : "http://test.png"
 },
 "3243121" : {
  "uid" : "3243121",
  "name" : "testuser2",
  "image" : "http://test.png"
 }
"list" : {
 "-JOFBZ6YFFdRfBNEe-DV" : {
   ".value" : true,
   ".priority" :1.401504809514409E12
 },
 "-JOFJTOnwADzfZmY0fMl" : {
   ".value" : true,
   ".priority" : 1.401506883247231E12
 },
```

I'd like to order data by list's priority. I define "list" and "person" node as below

```
[listRef setValue:@YES andPriority:ts];

[[[rootRef childByAppendingPath:@"person"] childByAppendingPath:userID] setValue:@{@"uid":userID, @"image":image, @"name":name}];
```

I don't understand why data is ordered automatically based "person" without priority not "list" priority.

Anybody have any idea??

Comment: The data is ordered lexicographically. So the users are ordered the same as if you called .sort() on an array containing those IDs.

Comment: Thank you for reply.Is it can be avoided to be ordered lexicographically?

Comment: Use .push() and the chronological ids provided by Firebase, or use priorities to specify a different order.

Comment: Thank you Kato. Could you let me ask? I tried to test some time again without changing my code, I found one things. When the data load first time, the data was ordered lexicographically based on userID, but after reload tableview data, it was ordered correctly chronologically as I desired. Although tried to again and again, first time load was always ordered lexicographically. I don't understand why only first time loading is like that. If you give me the clue, I think it may no need to change to chronological ids.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing a repro. Probably you are not observing [prevChild](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/Firebase.html#//api/name/observeEventType:andPreviousSiblingNameWithBlock:) and events are arriving at the client out of order? Unlikely.

Comment: Thank you for reply. ummm... I'm observing prevChild on top of nested observing as I wrote question. I can't find out the cause why first time loading is out of order and after reloading is ordered correctly... Firebase's observing has no difference at first time and second time? (sorry for my English...)

Comment: Resolved this issue by detecting first time or second time with BOOL but this is not correct way.. Thank you Kato.